# Populate textbox after scanning barcode

Tags: c#, database, textbox, barcode, barcode-scanner

Is it possible to fetch data from database after scanning the barcode? example my student ID is 201312345, after scanning my ID is it possible to populate the textboxes with my infos like name, address, course, et.?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

yes thats possible!

Put the scanned student ID in a variable, make a query where you select the things you want from your database

EXAMPLE:

SqlCommand sqlSelectStudentData = new SqlCommand(SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE studentid=@studentid);

sqlSelectStudentData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentid", 'your scanned student id');

Put the values that return from the query in some labels or in what objects you want.

Good Luck!

Comment: This is btw c# SQL code, dont know what you are using but the idea is the same in every code

Comment: Yeah I will be using C#, so this how I understand it. I scan the id first, then submit it and make the query, then once it's on the database, it will populate the corresponding textboxes? correct?, because I don't think it's possible that just by right after I scanned it will automatically populate the textboxes or is it?

Comment: What a scanner does is read the value you scan and push enter. First step: Scan barcode and put the scanned value in a variable Second step: Use the value of the variabel to make a query that gets your name, adress, course etc. Third step: The values that return from the query are your name, adress, course etc. Put those values in your label(Or so ever).

Answer (score 0):

```
string ValueOfScanner;

SqlCommand sqlcmGetStudentInfo = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE studentid=@studentid ", connectionstring);
GetStudentInfo.Paramaters.AddWithValue("@studentid", ValueOfScanner);
SqlDataReader msGetInfo = GetStudentInfo.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dtGetInfo= new DataTable();
dtGetInfo.Load(msGetInfo);

foreach(DataRow row in dtGetInfo.Rows)
{
    labelStudentName = row["studentinfo"].ToString();
    labelStudentAdress = row["studentadress"].ToString();
    labelStudentCourse = row["studentcourse"].ToString();
    labelStudentSchool = row["studentschool"].ToString(); 
    //And so on!
}
```

This is the code that should do the job. Make the query fit to your database and the tablename values to your tablenames. And put the value of what the scanner scans in the string ValueOfScanner!

Hope this helps you further

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is execute your SQL query in a TextBox TextChanged Event.

So when you scan your userId and the textbox is populated with the value, it will call a textChanged Event. This method will execute the query and get the information for the studentId from the Database that you can fill your form  or whatever you have.

This is how I will do it.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing special with it, the barcode scanner acts just like a keyboard and at the end of the reading it will emit an enter key so the only thing that you have to do is handle that event or whatever your logic is.